# Getting "Total number of messages on IoT hub exceeded the allocated quota" error even if usage is just 95.5KB

Tags: azure-iot-hub

I am using free tier IoT hub .
As per the document, https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/pricing/details/iot-hub/ ,
the documentation of Azure says 'the messages sent by devices connected via the free edition are metered in 0.5 KB blocks. For instance, if the device sends a 16 KB message via the IoT Hub free tier it will be billed as 32 messages"

There are two Devices only  and from portal I see total message size is 95.5 KB which is sum of these two devices and it is what shown in our Azure Data Explorer query as well .Please find screenshot at link below:
[Azure monitoring metrics screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/frsyA.png)

[Kusto telemetry screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XkiKc.png)

if we take the data from Azure portal it would be (95.5)/0.5=191 messages

Even though the allocated limit for free tier is 8000 messages per day , I am getting "Total number of messages on IoT hub exceeded the allocated quota" error with just 95.5 KB usage.

Please someone help me here to understand why I am getting this limit exceeded error even if I am nowhere near to the allocated limit.

Thanks in advance,
Sereena

Updated with 21/9/2020 screenshots .  @Stefan Wick MSFT please see below images

[Total messages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ACHao.jpg)

[C2D messages delivered](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rbhCD.png)

[C2D messages abandoned](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dbkxn.png)

[Device Twins Updates](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cMb0e.png)

[Total device data usage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4q5f0.png)

Error message:
"You've reached your daily message quota, so you won't be able to send new message or view device list. Because you're using the free edition of IoT Hub, you can't increase message quota. Wait util 12 AM UTC or create a hub using a paid plan"

Comment: Are you also sending messages or updates from the cloud to device? Or reporting property updates from the device in addition to your telemetry messages?

Comment: You might have hit the per sec or per min messaged limit.https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-devguide-quotas-throttling#operation-throttles

Comment: @ Stefan Wick MSFT, No messages or updates were sent from cloud to device. Please see attachments added today (edited yesterday's question - to add today's screenshots)

Comment: @iAviator, No, not hitting per sec or per min limit. Sending only 4 messages in one min

Comment: @Sereena can you create a new IoT Hub Free Tier and test your solution again? Thanks

Comment: @Sereena if you are now unblocked can you share with us the workaround as an answer? Thanks!

Comment: @asergaz, I contacted azure support and they are helping to figure it out. I will update here the details soon